# How to use Post Script Type 1 in new Lyx?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lyx, lyx-layouts, type1

I need to use Post Script Type 1 on my Lyx.

It seems this old article (https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips.InstallType1Fonts) is for the version of Lyx that relied on MikTex.

So right now here, I see only 3 options: Roman, Sans Serif, Typewriter

How can I expand the options?

[image]

Comment: LyX does not really have anything to do with that, it relies on the latex installation you're using, but you did not say anything about that

Comment: @daleif As was recommended at wiki.lyx.org/Windows/TeXLive, I installed TeXLive for that purpose. So do I have to do something directly on TeXLive?

Comment: If you installed the full texlive you should have all the fonts you need (miktex does not install everything, and is thus a little problematic at times). Perhaps you should rephrase your question to describe the problem you're having instead.

Comment: Everything that install type1 fonts link tells about it the fonts in the latex installation, and you should already have those. Plus that page is 14 years old, kinda out of date, even for miktex

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I just edited my question to include a screenshot.